# Convert percentage value to number in LESS

Tags: css, less

I need to convert percentage value (51%) to number (0.51)

What is the best way to do this?

My less snippet

```
// Gradients
#gradient {
    .vertical-gloss(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333, @firstColorStop:50%, @secondColorStart:51%) {
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, @startColor @firstColorStop, @endColor @secondColorStart);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, @startColor @firstColorStop, @endColor @secondColorStart);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, @startColor @firstColorStop, @endColor @secondColorStart);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, @startColor @firstColorStop, @endColor @secondColorStart);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, @startColor @firstColorStop, @endColor @secondColorStart);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.5, @startColor), color-stop(0.51, @startColor));
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use the [`unit` function](http://lesscss.org/#reference) to convert `50%` to 50.
2. Divide the result by 100. Don't forget to [wrap the calculation within parentheses](http://lesscss.org/#-operations) (parentheses are optional in LESS 1.3, but required in LESS 1.4).

For readability, I've used an auxiliary variable, as seen below:

```css
.vertical-gloss(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333, @firstColorStop:50%, @secondColorStart:51%) {
    @firstColorStopPerc: (unit(@firstColorStop) / 100);
    @secondColorStopPerc: (unit(@secondColorStart) / 100);
    /* ... skipped non-relevant pieces ... */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(@firstColorStopPerc, @startColor), color-stop(@secondColorStopPerc, @startColor));
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```